# How to show data that didn't match the creteria in mongoDB query aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

I have the problem with my query, I want to show all data with spesific date from the table called "login_page_view" that I join into the main table. and this is the result of that:

```
data: [
{
"_id": "645c3cc4c530d86431a6eb31",
 "id": 1897,
 "name": "Test",
"traffic: 
{
    "_id": "65b0e7a86a019968799e2e15",
     "higo_router_id": 1897,
     "weekday": "Tuesday",
     "date": "2023-12-31",
}
   "login_page_view": [
                {
                    "_id": "65b1cdfc7b0636032d99a23b",
                    "date": "2024-01-02"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65b1cffe7b0636032d99a23c",
                    "date": "2024-01-03"
                },

                    "_id": "65b1d3e47b0636032d99a247",
                    "date": "2024-01-02"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65b1d3ed7b0636032d99a248",
                    "date": "2024-01-03"
                },

            ],
},

]
```

and this is the query that I wrote:

```
    {
          $lookup: {
            from: "hotspotloginpageview",
            let: {
              routerId: "$id",
              trafficDate: "traffic.date",
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: ["$higo_router_id", "$$routerId"],
                  },
                  date: {
                    $gte: from_date,
                    $lte: until_date,
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  id: 1,
                  date: 1,
                },
              },
            ],
            as: "login_page_view",
          },
        }
```

I don't want to show all the date in the login_page_view but I want to filter it by date without using $match with traffic.date, because I can't get all the data. I already use $group, $unwind, or even filter them with javascript but nothing's work, is there anybody who know to where I did wrong?

this is the result I want:

```
data: [
{
"_id": "645c3cc4c530d86431a6eb31",
 "id": 1897,
 "name": "Test",
"traffic: 
{
    "_id": "65b0e7a86a019968799e2e15",
     "higo_router_id": 1897,
     "weekday": "Tuesday",
     "date": "2023-12-31",
}
   "login_page_view": [
                {
                    "_id": "65b1cdfc7b0636032d99a23b",
                    "date": "2024-01-02"
                },
                {

                    "_id": "65b1d3e47b0636032d99a247",
                    "date": "2024-01-02"
                },

            ],
},

{
"_id": "645c3cc4c530d86431a6eb31",
 "id": 1897,
 "name": "Test",
"traffic: Null, 
 "login_page_view": [
 
                {
                    "_id": "65b1cffe7b0636032d99a23c",
                    "date": "2024-01-03"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "65b1d3ed7b0636032d99a248",
                    "date": "2024-01-03"
                },

            ],
},

]
```